# Javascript view source html of another website

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm currently working on a simple webcrawler that will show all of the links the given site has. For example, this is what I would like my program to do:

-you give it a url : http://www.example.com/

-then the program gets the html source and looks for all of the `<a href=...></a>`tags

-finally, all of the links are shown to the user

To do this, I am using simple javacsript with jQuery, and am currently stuck on a $.ajax() call:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://example.com",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    crossDomain : true,
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }       
});
```

This throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error and I don't know how to fix this.

Is this behavior actually possible? If it's not, how can web-browsers actually show source code of any site? And if this is not the right way of getting HTML source, what is the right way?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Well in general a url isn't going to give back a JSONP response, unless you are specifically using an endpoint that does. Just setting dataType to JSONP does not magically make the server give one back, it has to support it

Comment: This is not going to work using ajax alone without using a proxy (either on your server or third party service) due to CORS restrictions

Comment: You're crawling a page to get links, this says that your `dataType` cannot be `jsonp` but rather it would be `html`

Comment: Also going to need to use a headless browser if the html in remote page is inserted using javascript after page loads...as is very common these days

Comment: @apokryfos I agree, but setting the dataType to html will not work because it will violate the cross-origin policy

Comment: If the remote servers cross origin policy only allows jsonp to be sent then you need a server-side solution like a proxy script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it up with php by creating a “proxy”. You can look it up on the web, but I recall it being something like:

**PROXY.PHP**

```
<?php
print file_get_contents($_POST[‘url’]);
?>
```

**ON JQUERY**
    var yourURL = “your url here”;
    $(“div”).load(“proxy.php?url=“+yourURL)

Feel free to ask for any doubt you may have
Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks, this is a relatively simple solution. But I would like to point out (according to my research) that you CAN'T access cross domain sites with just javascript. There are some edge cases (when the server supports CORS : https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) but you cannot expect this from any site.

Comment: That is right. And in most cases, the restriction is for security purposes for both you and the user. Imagine if someone displays your bank account page on their website with malicious code; or if someone submits a malicious code to your website.... I know the restriction is there for a purpose and would not recommend violating it